# How to check if specific table names exist in a database?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, database

All I want to do is check if a table exists or not and I can't figure it out.

I've tried:

```
for ($r = 0; $r < count($tableArray); $r++) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "select * from `#__".$tableArray[$r]."` LIMIT 1";
    $db->setQuery($query);

    if ($db->setQuery($query) !== False) {
        $results = $db->loadAssocList();
        echo "<br>".$tableArray[$r]."table found";
    } else {
        echo "<br>".$tableArray[$r]."table NOT found";
    }
}
```

I've also tried to get an array of Joomla table names that I can iterate through.

```
Array('table1','table2','table3' etc
```

I can do this with `SHOW TABLES`, but this produces a large array of arrays each with one entry.

---

### Solution I used:

I'm including what I did in the end; both answers were helpful.

I did this to get the array of the tables:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$results = $db->setQuery('SHOW TABLES')->loadColumn();
```

and then I used `in_array()` to find if the table I was looking for was there:

```
$prefix = $db->getPrefix();
for ($r = 0; $r < count($tableArray); $r++) {
    if (in_array($prefix.$tableArray[$r], $results)) {
        echo "<br>Found ".$tableArray[$r];
    }else{
        echo "<br>Missing ".$tableArray[$r];
    }
}
```

`$tableArray` is the array holding the table names to be checked.

Comment: When you have 15 rep points or more, you can upvote answers that you find helpful. I see from your edit, that it was not your `SHOW TABLES` query that was the problem, but your php conditional that was inhibiting things -- which only my answer addresses.  If you don't like my long-winded/convoluted queries, that's fine, but I would appreciate receiving an upvote for volunteering my time and delivering a comprehensive and working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `SHOW TABLES` load results with `loadColumn()` to receive a simple array with table names as values.

```
print_r(JFactory::getDbo()->setQuery('SHOW TABLES')->loadColumn());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tbl_assets
    [1] => tbl_associations
    [2] => tbl_banner_clients
    [3] => tbl_banner_tracks
    [4] => tbl_banners
...
)
```

Comment: Hey there - you put so much effort to write a good answer on the above question. This means that the question should be good too and was worthing an Up-vote. There is a button next to the question for upvoting. You should use it. Also there is another answer posted after yours. If you revisit this question - see what this answer is about. Do you think it's at all any helpful? Upvote it too.

Answer (score 4):

What is likely to be tripping you up is that your `$tableArray` doesn't have prefixes.  This is evident in your query because you prepend the tablename with `#__` in the `FROM` clause.  The resultset will be delivering the rendered prefix with the tablename, so your input array values will not match the result set values.

*Important: Always try to avoid iterated database queries as a matter of best practice.  Performing multiple queries unnecessarily will result in slow page loads not to mention burden your system.

I've tested the following to be successful on my localhost.  I've written this to be completely dynamic (no hardcoding the db name or table prefix).

If you don't want to filter the table names in the result set, you can use this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$results = $db->setQuery('SHOW TABLES')->loadColumn();

$prefix = $db->getPrefix();
foreach ($tableArray as $t) {
    echo "<br>" , (in_array($prefix.$t, $results) ? "Found " : "Missing ") , $t;
}
```

Otherwise, you can filter the result set by extending the query logic.

Code:

```
$tableArray = ["banners", "content", "cucumbers"];
try {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $dbname = $config->get('db');
    $prefix = $db->getPrefix();
    foreach ($tableArray as $t) {
        $q_tablenames[] = $db->q($prefix.$t);  // prefix and quote-wrap for the query
    }
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select("SUBSTRING(table_name, 7)")
        ->from("information_schema.tables")
        ->where(["table_schema = " . $db->q($dbname), "table_name IN (" . implode(',', $q_tablenames) . ")"]);
    // echo $query->dump();    // never show to public
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $found = $db->loadColumn();
    foreach ($tableArray as $tablename) {
        echo "<div>$tablename table " , (in_array($tablename, $found) ? "" : "not ") , "found</div>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');    // never show actual error to public
}
```

Output:

```
banners table found
content table found
cucumbers table not found
```

---

The reason that I am using a more verbose query is because I don't actually *need* to extract *every* table name from the database -- I only need the ones that exist in the array.  This is more about "direct coding intentions" rather than micro-optimization (which I won't bother to benchmark).

The `IN` data is prefixed because the `$tableArray` values are not pre-fitted with prefixes.  The `SELECT` trims off the prefixes for simple comparisons in the `foreach()` loop.

---

Here is an alternative approach using `SHOW TABLES` which achieves the same result:

```
$tableArray = ["banners", "content", "cucumbers"];
try {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $dbname = $config->get('db');
    $prefix = $db->getPrefix();
    foreach ($tableArray as $t) {
        $q_tablenames[] = $db->q($prefix . $t);  // prefix and quote-wrap for the query
    }
    $db->setQuery("SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db->qn($dbname) . " WHERE " . $db->qn("Tables_in_$dbname") . " IN (" . implode(',', $q_tablenames) . ")");
    $found = $db->loadColumn();
    foreach ($tableArray as $tablename) {
        echo "<div>$tablename table " , (in_array($prefix.$tablename, $found) ? "" : "not ") , "found</div>";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');    // never show to public
}
```

Comment: Hey there - you put so much effort to write a good answer on the above question. This means that the question should be good too and was worthing an Up-vote. There is a button next to the question for upvoting. You should use it. Also there was already another answer on this question. Do you think it's at all any helpful? Upvote it too.

Comment: The other answer didn't solve the actual problem - it gave good advice about how to extract the resultset from a query that the OP had already tried.  Not every question that can be answered deserves an upvote - my criteria are not that simple.

Comment: I have been generous in my service toward this OP in several ways -- far more valuable than mere points.

Comment: I feel this question could have been more clear by providing sample data for the input array and the expected result.  As it was posted, it was obviously not clear what the isolated issue was judging by how Sharky's answer didn't fix the issue. The accepted answer should be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: Minor quibble with @mickmackusa's second answer - `SUBSTRING(table_name, 7)` assumes the prefix length is 6 chars including underscore. Whilst this is true for new (post j2.5) standard installs, if the site has been around a while, or if a longer or shorter prefix was specified during installation, the query will fail to find a match.